# How do I install UControl

Tags: bluetooth, ipod, install-from-source, custom-installer

How do I install UControl from http://www.negusoft.com/index.php/ucontrol-downloads

It comes in a tar.gz. I unpacked it and tried fallowing the readme but am getting nowhere. What are the steps to take?

I am trying to set up my iPod with my computer so I can have a track pad over Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific as to where you're faltering?  The instructions in the readme file seem pretty straight forward, but maybe it's because I'm used to Linux.  Open terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
sudo apt-get install libbluetooth-dev 

cd ~/whateverdirectoryyouunpackedto/
sudo sh install

That should be it, unless you get errors in which case report those.  Then you can run by the launcher in your applications or by typing

ucontrol 

at the terminal.  Are your running a 32 bit system?  This package says that 64 bit is unsupported.
```

Comment: Thank you I was able to install it but when I try running it it comes up with "Unable to access jarfile /usr/lib/ucontrol.jar"

Comment: ok I got it to sort of work. If I find the jar file and tell it to open in java then it opens. How can I get it to automatically open in java and how can I get it to show up in my applications menu?

Comment: I think that's a more generalized question worthy of it's own question.  Glad you got things "sorta working" but I think reposting your new more speicific question would get you better answers.